# phone number validation wont pass

Tags: javascript

```
function ClientContactCheck(){
    var clientcontact = $("#client_contact_id").val();

    if(clientcontact.length != ""){
    if(!isNaN(clientcontact)){
        $("#client_contact_id").css('border-color', "#dfe0e6");
        return true;
    }
    }else{
        $("#client_contact_id").css('border-color', "red");
    }

return false;
}
```

i am using this function to validation phone number , my intention is simple just not be empty and must be number.

but if put !isNaN and my input was 123-456-789 , it wont valid cause the  -  was not a number, how to i make my function bypass the - ?

so if the input value had - it will pass thought.

thank

Comment: First and foremost, `(clientcontact.length != "")` will always be true since `clientcontact.length` since `length` method returns integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it with a regular expression:

```
var clientcontact = $("#client_contact_id").val();
if (/^[0-9\-]+$/.test(clientcontact)) {
    $("#client_contact_id").css('border-color', "#dfe0e6");
    return true;
} else {
    $("#client_contact_id").css('border-color', "red");
    return false;
}
```

This will allow `'-', '--', '---'` too. If that is not desired, you can do one more check: `... && !/^-*$/.test(clientcontact)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
 str.replace("-", "");
```

and then check your input if it is a number only.

Edit:

```
var res = str.replace(/\-/g,'');
```

Comment: This removes only the first hyphen

Comment: Use it like this : var res = str.replace(/\-/g,' ');

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to validate the phone number.

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt)
{
  var phoneno = /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))
        {
      return true;
        }
      else
        {
        alert("message");
        return false;
        }
}
```

More at http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php